# what is the reason i am getting out put is 111?

Tags: c++, templates

## include "stdafx.h"

```
#include<iostream.h>

template<class T>
class Sample
{
    public:
        Sample();
        static int i;



};
template<class T>
int Sample<T>::i = 0;
template<class T>
Sample<T>::Sample()
{
    i++;
    cout<<i;
}

void main()
{
    Sample<int>s1;
    Sample<float>s2;
    Sample<char>s3;
}
```

output: 111

what is the reason i am getting out put is 111?

Comment: In the future, please format your code by selecting it and clicking the "101010" button in the editor.

Comment: yes, 3 aces. what did you expect?

Comment: what were you expecting to get?

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` is a VS abomination and it's not needed for this example. There is no header `<iostream.h>`. it's `<iostream>` instead. And it's `std::cout`. Oh, and you get this output because that's how the language is defined. (If you want a better explanation, you should state your expectations and how the result deviates from them.)

Answer (score 7):

The reason that the output is `111` (as opposed to `123`) is that `Sample<int>`, `Sample<float>` and `Sample<char>` are three completely different types, and therefore they each have their own, separate  static variable called `i`.

You have a template called `Sample`, and each time you instantiate it with a different template argument, it uses that template to create a new class on the fly, based on the template. But the classes created using the template do not have a relationship to each other, and do not share static information.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the line

```
Sample<float> s2_2;
```

to `main()` (which should return an `int`, incidentally). This should help to illustrate what others have already answered.

In addition, you could include the type information in your output:

```
#include <typeinfo>
:
:
template<class T>
Sample<T>::Sample()
{
    i++;
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ':' << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Sample<int>::i`, `Sample<float>::i` and `Sample<char>::i` are three different variables. Hence you're getting 111.

Answer (score 1):

`Sample` is a class template that is used to create three distinct classes in this case, each with its own distinct `i`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a template class with a static member variable the compiler is supposed to ensure that for "each" typename T, there is one and only one copy of the static variable. Since you have instantiated Sample class with three different types, you see the output as "1" for each type.

Answer (score 0):

`Sample<int>`, `Sample<float>`, `Sample<char>` are three different types and each has its own static variable.

If you wanted to get `123` you would have had to put `static int i` in a common base class.